# Facebook messages just queue up forever?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written an app that talks to Facebook messenger.  I kept getting the same message from Facebook over and over.

(It's an Express app)

```
app.post('/webhook23', (req, res) => {
```

(This is the quantity that was the same each time I got messaged)

```
req.body.entry[0].messaging.events[0]
```

(Here's what I got)

```
{
   "sender":{
      "id":"1075583395843601"
   },
   "recipient":{
      "id":"1408746912473828"
   },
   "timestamp":1472824205937,
   "message":{
      "mid":"mid.1472824205931:3f118e895201854e72",
      "seq":122,
      "text":"Yes."
   }
}
```

I eventually broke out of this by writing a little program that accepted whatever Facebook said, and returned a 200 status.  I drained the pipe, and then I was able to work.

Am I understanding this correctly though?  It'll just keep on trying forever?  Further messages just wait until the one in front is successfully processed?  Is this a good design?

Regards, Rick

Comment: Yes, Facebook keeps re-sending webhook updates (with decreasing frequency, for up to 24 hours), until your callback URL responds with a status code 200.

Comment: Hmm.  So I guess that's a good design because you might only be available intermittently?  I guess that makes sense.  Thanks, @CBroe!